# backend services for App building on Azure

Tags: mobile, azure

Is there any framework I can Instal on windows azure and get a service similar to parse.com, AppMobi, kinvey etc.?

I would use this services to simplify my life, but if there was some reliable framework that I can put on windows azure and help me with all push notifications, and creating the rest API I would prefer it over kinvey or similar services because I can have control over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few examples you could leverage:

http://watwp.codeplex.com/

http://watgames.codeplex.com/

http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/08/windows-azure-toolkits-for-devices-now-with-android/

But I don't think they are quite the same as what you are referring to.  But you could use these to build your own.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/)is a little closer

Comment: [This link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/mobile-services/) is a bit more direct, and provides an overview of the Backend-as-a-Service capabilities of Azure Mobile Services.